# Is every polynomial ring over any field regular?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, regular-rings

> Is every polynomial ring over any field regular?

For a field that is algebraically closed, it is true as any maximal ideal of $k[x_1,...,x_n]$ corresponds to a point $(t_1,...,t_n)$ in $\mathbb{A}^n$ and thus is generated by $n$ elements $x_i-t_i$. But when $k$ is not algebraically closed, does one still have the same conclusion?

Comment: Wikipedia thinks so: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_ring (specifically: any field is regular, and if $A$ is a regular ring, so is $A[x]$).

Comment: Theorem 5.1 in Matsumura's "Commutative Ring Theory" gives an elementary direct proof that any maximal ideal in $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ has $n$ generators for an arbitrary field $k$.  So there is no need to first treat the algebraically closed case and to then deduce the general case from that.

Comment: ...every polynomial ring _in finitely many indeterminates_...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this follows from the homological characterization of regularity.  Let $A=k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ and $B=K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, where $K$ is the algebraic closure of $k$.  Then for any $A$-modules $M$ and $N$ with $M$ finitely generated, $$B\otimes \operatorname{Ext}_A^*(M,N)=\operatorname{Ext}_B^*(B\otimes M,B\otimes N).$$  Since $B$ has global dimension $n$, the right hand side vanishes for $*>n$, and hence so does $\operatorname{Ext}_A^*(M,N)$.  It follows that $A$ has global dimension $n$ and is thus regular.  Alternatively, there are various ways to prove directly that $A$ has finite global dimension, without reducing to the algebraically closed case (for instance, you can show that the global dimension of $R[x]$ is always one more than the global dimension of $R$).

Comment: There is no need to consider B, in that it is difficult to provr that B has finite global dimension without proving atmthe same time that A has finite global dimension  :-). A itself has finite global dimension: this follows at once from the fact that its projective dimension as a bimodule over itself is finite, and this last can be seen by looking at a Koszul complex.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: don't you have to have a local ring for the Koszul complex of regular sequence to be free resolution of the quotient?

Comment: @Alex, the Koszul complex for a regular sequence is always exact ---whether the ring is local or not.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Okay, now that I recall the proof, it doesn't have to be local. Thanks.